# Center spinner div in side menu even when scroll appears

Tags: html, css

I have one spinner component which I can add on different parts of the page (where ever it is needed). Spinner is always centered according to its parent. Parent is in relative position and spinner is absolute. The main problem is when some of the spinner container is scrollable. In the scrolled content spinner is not centered any more. I know that for scrolled content we can use position fixed to center content but it works only if content should be centered on whole page.

Is it possible to somhow achive this in my case ? Image of example page and code are below.

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 26%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 70%
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.side-menu {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.spinner {
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>

    <div class="spinner-wrapper">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      Content

      <div class="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-menu">
      Side menu

      <div class="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: show your html code

Comment: Sorry I forgot, everything is here now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a overflow:hidden in your css to prevent scrollable content.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 26%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 70%
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.side-menu {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.spinner {
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    Header

    <div class="spinner-wrapper">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      Content

      <div class="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-menu">
      Side menu

      <div class="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Spinner should appear after some time in some moment, in that moment user maybe already scrolled content down. If we set "overflow: hidden" in that moment, as far as I see we will not achieve anything.

Comment: You set overflow hidden on the spinner item. Not on the whole content...

Comment: Of course. You did it for header. I updated my example with some text in the header.
Run snippet, scroll down header, set overflow to hidden in debug mode and you will see that spinner was left above.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let w = screen.width;
w = w/2;
var a = document.getElementById('spinner-wrapper').style.left = w + 'px';

function myFunction() {
  let w = window.innerWidth;
  console.log(w);
  w = w/2;
  console.log(w);
  let a = document.getElementById('spinner-wrapper').style.left = w + 'px';
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 26%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 70%
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.side-menu {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.spinner {
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body onresize="myFunction()">
  <div class="header">
    Header

    <div class="spinner-wrapper" id="spinner-wrapper">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      Content

      <div class="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-menu">
      Side menu

      <div class="spinner-wrapper" id="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

plz check

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 26%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 70%
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.side-menu {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 100;
}

.spinner {
  border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 8px solid #3498db;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  position: fixed;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </br></br></br></br>

    <div class="spinner-wrapper">
      <div class="spinner"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">
      Content

      <div class="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="side-menu">
      Side menu

      <div class="spinner-wrapper">
        <div class="spinner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems that this is work, thank you. You set "position: fixed" on spinner element. 
The only problem here is that spinner-wrapper element is not extended to the bottom if we scroll down. If we want to set some background to it, we will not see that background if scroll down.